# Storing html into a JS variable

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm trying to save html into a JS variable

```
var popupBody = '<%= MyContext.Current.DynamicProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyName == "PopupModalBody").PropertyValue %>';
```

Above code will try to store html returned by C# to a JS variable (popupBody) but it returns Syntax Error in the console because the html is not in a single line. How can I achieve this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you can append Replace function and use like`PropertyValue.Replace("\r\n","")`

Comment: try to use template string https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thanks @KD, you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template string instead of this. It is part of ES6 and make sure your browser supports this.

```
var popupBody = `<%= MyContext.Current.DynamicProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyName == "PopupModalBody").PropertyValue %>`;
```

**[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**

Comment: Could you suggest any other approach? because as you know this trick has problems with older browsers.

Comment: a simplest way of doing this would be... adding this value to a <div style="display:none" id="htmlContent">.  then using document.getElementById("htmlContent").innerHTML access this content in your variable and use it further. as you can also destroy the DIV after this. One more way would be to replace all \n\r with empty string while assignment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an ASP.net (assuming that's the case from the `<%= %>`) programmer, but the general idea, no matter which templating or programming language you're generating JavaScript in is that you can use JSON encoding for JavaScript literals.

So -- *assuming* there's something like `Json.Encode` available in the template:

```
var popupBody = <%= Json.Encode(MyContext.Current.DynamicProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyName == "PopupModalBody").PropertyValue) %>;
```

Note the lack of quotes; the JSON encoder will add those, as it's encoding a string.

Comment: For others, I tried using the similar approach and it worked for me, try this JSON.ToJSON()